# Need to print out line of array if the first word matched the user input

Tags: java

i have an array that contains courses that was made from a txt file:

```
arr[1] = CSC 110 Fundamentals of Programming I
arr[2] = PHYS 102 General Physics
arr[3] = MATH 100 Calculus I
arr[4] = CSC 167 Video Game Interaction and Design
arr[5] = ECON 103 Principles of Microeconomics
```

My method:

```
public static void listCoursesInDept(String targetDept, UvicCourse[] arr){}
```

takes a department name (ex: csc) and searches through the array to find a line that contains the department. If the depatement name matches the one in the array the entire line (department, number and name) gets printed.

I am wondering how I can compare the targetDept to the first word or each line in the array.

Comment: You can create a for loop and compare his elements with the targst

Comment: To start with something, have a look at the startsWith method of class String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to store them in a map and get the value using the key.

```
Map<String, String> departments = new HashMap<String, String>();
String findKey = "CSC1";
departments.put("CSC", "CSC 110 Fundamentals of Programming I");
departments.put("PHYS", "PHYS 102 General Physics");
departments.put("MATH", "MATH 100 Calculus I");

if(departments.containsKey(findKey))
{
    System.out.println( findKey + " --- " + departments.get(findKey));
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Invalid Couse");
}
```

*UPDATE*

using arrays is similar, you have to exploit string methods.

```
List<String> departments = new ArrayList<String>();
String findKey = "CSC1";
departments.add("CSC 110 Fundamentals of Programming I");
departments.add("PHYS 102 General Physics");
departments.add("CSC 167 Video Game Interaction and Design");
boolean found = false;
for(String department : departments)
{
    if(department.startsWith(findKey))
    {
        found = true;
        System.out.println(department);
    }
}
if(!found)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid Cource");
}
```